# Are class, object, and constructor function equivalent?

Tags: function, class, object, properties, ecmascript-6

Now that JS has`class`, I was wondering if there were differences between these 3 "station". Are there the same/equivalent ?
In all cases, I can access the label with `station.label`

```
//1
export class Station {

    public label: string;
    public code: number;

    constructor(label, code) {
        this.code = code;
        this.label = label;
    }
}
let station = new Station("my label", "my code");

//2    
function Station(label, code) {
    this.label = label;
    this.code = code;
}
let station = new Station("my label", "my code");

// 3
let station = { label: "my label", "code": my code }
```

Answer (score 0):

lets say it like this: in all cases you get a new object with label & code property ;)

in the end class gets transpiled into function:

```
class A { 
    ...
}
```

gets transpiled into smth like:

```
var A = function A() { 
    _classCallCheck(this, A);
};
```

so you get an equivalent return but how to create instances will differ a bit ;)

e.g.
example 1 & 2 -> `new Station()`
example 3 -> `Object.create(Station.prototype)`